# Updating standard objects from Online submissions

Tags: force.com-sites, standard-objects, update, google-apps

How do I update records in Leads / Contact object through online submission (Force.com Site). I know it doesn't allow direct updates but is there an indirect way to do this? How?

Second is I want to create and update standard objects through Google forms. How do I do this?

I do not want to use Communities as this is for a Non-Profit Organization. If you can provide some detailed steps it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force.com sites does not support Update, Delete, Usert. Only insert is possible through Site.com form.

Alternatively you can write a trigger on the object and use some variable which update through Site.com form and from which you can identify which operation need to do.

Natively it is not supported.